# How can we add a dynamic row at the beginning of a table of antd in Reactjs while other rows remain static data fetched from the API?

Tags: reactjs, antd, web-frontend

I have created a table that contains two columns. The data on the
table is fetched through an API and passed to as a prop to the Table
Component. Now I want to add a new element to the table. So when I
click the New Button, a row will be created at the beginning of the
table. In that row, one column will be the input text and another
column will be a dropdown.

Till I am able to do it by passing a condition in the title of the table. like given below

```
  <Table
            dataSource={data}
            rowSelection={rowSelection}
            columns={columns}
            pagination={{
              hideOnSinglePage: true,
            }}
            rowClassName={record =>
              record.name === variable ? 'table-primary' : 'bg-white'
            }
            rowKey={record => record}
            onRow={record => ({
              onClick: () => {
                selectVariable(record);
              },
            })}
            bordered
            title={() =>
              flagData ? (
                <Row>
                  <Col lg={4} xl={4}>
                    <Input
                      placeholder="Enter Variable Name"
                      onChange={handleVariableName}
                      value={variableName}
                      style={{ width: 170 }}
                    />
                  </Col>
                  <Col lg={4} xl={4}>
                                  //Selecting a value from the dropdown
                    <Select
                      showSearch
                      style={{ width: 180, marginLeft: '150px' }}
                      
                      placeholder="Enter Entity Name"
                      onChange={value => handleEntityName(value)}
                      filterOption={(input, option) =>
                        option.props.children
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                      }
                    > 
                      {EntityName.map(item => {
                        return (
                          <Option key={item} value={item}>
                            {item}
                          </Option>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Select>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              ) : null
            }
          />
        </div>
```

But it is not in the desired location. Instead, it should be inside the table.

Any insight on this would really help. TIA

[image]

Comment: antd already supports adding new row. You can this: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row

Comment: Yes, by appending a new object to the datasource of the table.
So are you suggesting to save the data from the props into a local state and then try to append an input element and a dropdown in the columns ?

Comment: Yes, and instead of some random data, try putting some null/empty data. For saving, you can extract the newly added data from the data source state may be and save to backend..